# Raspberry Pi Camera uv4l stream a recording at the same time with Picamera

Tags: python, raspicam, streaming-video, uv4l

Im using uv4l to stream from my raspberry pi, and it works perfectly but if i wanna use a python script to record while streaming i'm getting this error:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x24a6300 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

My guess is that two process can't use the same resource in this case the camera, so that leave me with the question: is there a way to do this with python? the thing i'm building a security system and using python and i'm trying to record video when you detect a person but i should be able to still stream the video while the system is recording it.

this is my code for recording video right now that i'm testing

```
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.start_recording('my_video.h264')
    camera.wait_recording(6)
    camera.stop_recording()
```

as you can see is a simple recording method to run on python3 i need to at least fetch the streaming and save it. But it seems imposible the most close i've found on internet is how to take a screenshot with an opencv code but not saving video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use python script as a wrapper to embed a ffmpeg / avconv capture command .. this is much more easy and works fine... assuming you're using uv4l-server :

generate a stream capture of your device /dev/videoX -> uv4l-raspicam driver -> uv4-server:port

launch a service that calls a python script using process.call with :

```
 avconv/ffmpeg -i http://uv4lserver_address:uv4l_port/stream/video.mjpeg or(x264) -vf  /your_output_dir/filename.videoformat
```

Comment: I'm trying this but it shows only an image for the time i spend recording it         seems it's not refreshing ffmpeg -r 30 -i http://127.0.0.1:8080/stream/video.mjpeg try.avi -y

Comment: I actually success to open the video with omxplay but i need to open it with vlc

Comment: did you try .flv output format to be read by vlc ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as i thought the problem is that two different process can't use the same camera, but what i did was to use the streaming address and record it in to a file and send it to my server. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import time
import subprocess
import os.path
import pathlib
import base64
from API import ApiComunicacion

class Camera():

    def __init__(self,recording):
        self.recording = recording
        self.api = ApiComunicacion()

    def record_video(self):
        print('Recording')
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/stream/video.mjpeg'
        local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        # NOTE the stream=True parameter
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+'.mp4'
        save_path = '/home/pi/Downloads/tesis/video'
        completed_video= os.path.join(save_path, filename)

        i=0
        with open(completed_video, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
                if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    f.write(chunk)
                    i = i + 1
                    #f.flush() commented by recommendation from J.F.Sebastian
                    if(self.recording == False or i==10000):
                        print('Sending')
                        f.close()
                        with open(completed_video,'rb') as f:
                            video = f.read()
                            encode_video = base64.encodebytes(video)

                            json = {'ip_address': '10.10.10.110',
                                    'date': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                                    'video': encode_video}

                            r = self.api.post(json,'createvideo')
                            a = r.json()
                            print(a)
                            path = pathlib.Path(completed_video)
                            path.unlink()
                            f.close()
                            break
        return local_filename

    def recording(self):
        self.recording = not self.recording

camera = Camera(True)

camera.record_video()
```

so in other words i'm not using the camera two times i'm recording from the streaming of UV4L and then to send it to my server i encode the video with base 64 and send it